# Выйти (где?) на перроне - можно так?

Tags: падежи

Нужно для размера стиха 
написать 
выйти не на перрон, а на перроне. 
Совсем нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ничего делать для размера стиха. Как правило это говорит только о бедности языка автора.

По поводу грамматики. Мне трудно придумать осмысленную фразу с таким управлением. Но еще труднее давать советы отвлеченно от самого текста. Что у вас там происходит-то? Герой выходит из поезда? Так тут однознчно - куда. На перрон.

Если он там чего-то пытался на ходу сделать (шапку надеть или фамилию вспомнить) - и все никак не выходило, а вот **на перроне** вдруг вышло, то пользуйтесь на здоровье.
//---

Интересно, в гугле есть примеры "вышел на пероне", но все-таки это не нормативное использование.

Но вот сообразил почти нефантастический контекст.
Идет электричка. Платформа (ну "перрон" - в первом приближении) короче длины поезда. И вот часть пассажиров прыгает на шпалы и гравий. А везунчики - **выходят на перроне**. Тоже, конечно, не самый высокий стиль, но хоть осмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

**ПЕРРОН**, -а; м. [франц. perron] Площадка у железнодорожного пути на станции для пассажиров.  Выйти на п.

**В Нацкопусе**  тоже  "выходят на перрон", например: Оказывается, когда она уже села в поезд, к ней подошел офицер милиции и предложил **выйти на перрон**. [А. Д. Сахаров.

В то же время существует выражение "выйти на станции", а перрон ― это часть станции, можно бы применить метонимию (перенос по смежности с целого на часть).

Другой вариант ― это  скорректировать содержание стихотворение: вышли, встали на перроне.

Comment: Цитирую: ... Лишь смыслы, обжигая кожу, тревожат душу. Знаешь, я, пожалуй, выйду на перроне, у перекрёстка бытия. И обретать себя, живую, пойду, с опорой на перо...

Comment: Здесь всё нормально, поскольку смысл "в каком месте пути (_где_)" выходят, а не "_куда_ выходят из стоящего поезда".

Comment: Здесь подходит только форма (где?)  "на перроне", она же поддерживается и вторым обстоятельством.

Answer (score 0):

В более очевидном выражении "выйти на станции" станция выступает как объект на пути следования поезда, это указание на то, на каком элементе пути (**где**) выходят. Из остановившегося на станции поезда выходят только (**куда**) "**на перрон**" *станции*. Однако возможен контекст,  в котором перрон фигурирует как место остановки поезда, противопоставляемое другому месту, где на той же станции можно выйти. Например:

> Когда поезд подъезжает к крупной конечной станции, пассажиры **выходят
>   на перроне**, а машинист едет дальше и выходит в (области) депо.

Так что, если в вашем стихе пассажиры вышли на перроне, а покинутый ими усталый поезд грустно поплёлся в депо, то всё нормально.

Comment: *пассажиры выходят на перроне* - не, не катит. На остановке они выходят, на станции. На перроне они **остаются.**